# map and filter function in selector

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My selector checks all actions from array and then deletes empty elements. Can it be written better?

```js
const makeSelectError2 = (actions) =>
  createSelector(selectError, (errorState) =>
    actions
      .map((action) =>
        errorState[action] !== undefined ? errorState[action] : null,
      )
      .filter((action) => action)
      .find((action) => true),
  );
```

Comment: You can combine `map()` and `filter()` using `reduce()`, but your code is fine.

Comment: @Barmar, I added that I only need to take the first element from this array

Comment: If you just want the first element use `[0]`.

Comment: This is a selector and I want it to always return the first item in an array

Comment: [codereview.se] is the place to ask for improvements in coding style of working code.

Comment: And why won't `[0]` do that?

Comment: I don't know. This looks very bad for me

Comment: The `Array.prototype.shift` function may look cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the difference between `undefined` and `null` in your case? Both are returning `false`, and instead of `find` just get first element.

So we can write much shorter code:

```js
actions.map(action => errorState[action]).filter(Boolean)[0]
```

**Update:** Actually, if you need just first element then from the very beginning:

```js
errorState[actions.find(action => errorState[action])]
```

And that's it.

Comment: Instead of calling `[0]`, I would use `.shift()`.

Comment: yes, I always want the first element, but first I want to clear arrays of empty elements to always get the element

Comment: @reactdto2, your code doesnt clear arrays, map and filter are creating copy, they dont change array itself

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Array.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) you can combine map and filter into one by either returning an array with one item or zero items for each item processed.

So

```
actions
  .flatMap((action) => !!errorState[action] 
                       ? [ errorState[action] ] 
                       : []
  )[0]
```

Comment: looks cool, but I prefer the solution errorState[actions.find(action => errorState[action])]